# Using buttons to calculate output in Jupyter

Tags: button, jupyter

First time posting here so apologies if I mess up the formatting. I've just started using Jupyter today and my plan was to set up a really basic calculation where I'd define two variables using sliders (asset allocation) and two variables from Excel (Expected Returns). I'd then click a button, and calculate the weighted average return for the whole portfolio. I got quite far, but I can't seem to make the button run the calculation at the end (I get a Traceback and Object non-callable errors).

Can someone highlight where I've gone wrong? I know it is in the last paragraph somewhere!

Thanks

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from bqplot import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Import risk and return assumptions from Excel and assign data to variables
assumptions=pd.read_excel (r'/Users/samwreford/Documents/Assumptions.xlsx')
equityReturnAssumption=(assumptions['Expected Return'][0])
bondReturnAssumption=(assumptions['Expected Return'][1])

#Define two sliders for the asset allocation, as well as a text description and a button to calculate total return
sliderA = widgets.FloatSlider(value=1, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.01, description = 'Equities', readout_format='.1%')
sliderB = widgets.FloatSlider(value=0, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.01, description = 'Bonds', readout_format='.1%')
caption = widgets.HTML(value='Enter the value of Equities and Bonds')
calculate = widgets.Button(description="Calculate Return")
display(caption, sliderA, sliderB,calculate)

#Adjust sliders to make sure the asset allocation sums to 100%
def ifSliderAChanges(change):
        sliderB.value = 1-sliderA.value
sliderA.observe(ifSliderAChanges, names='value')
def ifSliderBChanges(change):
        sliderA.value = 1-sliderB.value
sliderB.observe(ifSliderBChanges, names='value')

#When button is clicked, calculate the total return and print to screen
def on_button_clicked(a,b):
    totalReturn=a*equityReturnAssumption + b*bondReturnAssumption
    print(totalReturn)

calculate.on_click(on_button_clicked(sliderA.value, sliderB.value))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to pass values into a function from a Jupyter Widget button on_click. Try this instead.

```py
#When button is clicked, calculate the total return and print to screen
def on_button_clicked(change):
    totalReturn = sliderA.value * equityReturnAssumption + sliderB.value * bondReturnAssumption
    print(totalReturn)

calculate.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```